# Formatting HTML Tables for Excel

Tags: excel, asp-classic, formatting, html-table

I have a page in asp that makes a xls table, however when open the table all the rows are stuffed into the default column width which I would like to set.

My table looks something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
'A for loop makes a series of th 
</thead>
'another loop pulls db values
<tr><td>value1</td><td>value2</td> 'etc </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried the following to set the space

- width="3.29in"
- &nsp; spam (barbaric but sometimes effective)
- width="400px"
- style="width:300px"

none of the above seem to work.

Additionally here is my header asp incase its relevant

```
Response.Clear()
Response.Buffer = False
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=blah.xls"
```

Also on a side note for some reason when I have a dollar value printed as such

```
<td>$<%=dbvalue%></td>
```

for some reason this yields '$dollar value and I am not sure how to nuke the single quote.

Comment: what happens if you dont use the 'th' series and keep them as 'td' ? you could add the style of the td as font-weight

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the thead tag? Something like this should work:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Report Title</h1>
<table >
<tr>
 <th style="width : 300px">header1</th>
 <th style="width : 100px">header2</th>
 <th style="width : 200px">header..</th>
 <th style="width : 300px">....</th>
</tr>
<tr class="row1">
 <td >value1</td>
 <td >value2</td>
 <td >value..</td>
 <td >....</td>
</tr>
....
```

Optionally you can put the table row with th tags inside a <thead> tag

Comment: doesn't have an effect on the final xls <tr> <thead> <td> <th> or other wise,

Comment: The above code works for me in Excel 2007. If it's not an excel version issue, there's probably either something before your table that causes havoc, or there is something wrong in your for loop. Try to open the actual created xls with a text editor to see what kind of html is actually created and fix it there first.